# Dynamically filter list and remove item in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data (represented in a list in my code):

```py
word_list = [{'bottom': Decimal('58.650'),  
  'text': 'Contact'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('77.280'),  
  'text': 'email@domain.com'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('101.833'),
  'text': 'www.domain.com'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('116.233'),
  'text': '(Acme INC)'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
  'text': 'Oliver'
 },
 {'bottom': Decimal('90.662'),
  'text': 'CEO'
 }]
```

The above data is coming from a PDF text extraction. I am trying to parse this and keep the layout formatting, based on the `bottom` values.

The thought is to check the `bottom` value for the current word, and then find **all** matching words, that is *within* a specific range with a tolerance of `threshold=`.

This is my code:

```py
threshold = float('10')
current_row = [word_list[0], ]
row_list = [current_row, ]

for word in word_list[1:]:

    if abs(current_row[-1]['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= threshold:
       # distance is small, use same row
       current_row.append(word)
    else:
       # distance is big, create new row
       current_row = [word, ]
       row_list.append(current_row)
```

So this will return a list of the words *within* the approved threshold.

I am a bit stuck here, since it may happen that when iterating the list, that words will have `bottom` values that are very close to each other, and thus it will select the same close words in multiple iterations.

For example, if a word has a bottom value that is close to a word that is already added to the `row_list`, it will simply just add it to the list again.

I was wondering if it was maybe possible to delete the words that's already been iterated/added? Something like:

```py
if abs(current_row[-1]['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= threshold:
   [...]
else:
   [...]

del word from word_list
```

However I am not sure how to implement this? As I cannot modify the `word_list` within the loop.

Comment: your `word_list` variable is of type `string`. First you will need to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the sorting parameter, e.g.

```
word_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['bottom'])
```

This results in

```
word_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['bottom'])
rows = []
current = [word_list.pop(0)]  # reversing the sort and using pop() is more efficient
while word_list:
    if word_list[0]['bottom'] - current[-1]['bottom'] < threshold:
        current.append(word_list.pop(0))
    else:
        rows.append(current)
        current = [word_list.pop(0)]
rows.append(current)
```

The code iterates through `word_list` until it is empty. The current word (at position 0, though reversing would increase efficiency) is compared to the last ordered word. End result is (`pprint.pprint(rows)`):

```
[[{'bottom': Decimal('58.650'), 'text': 'Contact'}],
 [{'bottom': Decimal('74.101'), 'text': 'Oliver'},
  {'bottom': Decimal('77.280'), 'text': 'email@domain.com'}],
 [{'bottom': Decimal('90.662'), 'text': 'CEO'}],
 [{'bottom': Decimal('101.833'), 'text': 'www.domain.com'}],
 [{'bottom': Decimal('116.233'), 'text': '(Acme INC)'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop instead of for loop

```
while len(word_list[1:])!=0:
    word=word_list[1] #as you are deleting item once it is used, next item will come to the beginning of list automatically
    word_list.remove(word)
    if abs(current_row[-1]['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= threshold:
       [...]
    else:
       [...]
```

Comment: When using this `while` statement, the code never finishes - seems like it's running an infinite loop? I can't see how it will ever reach `0`?

Comment: (Also, the `del word from word_list` is not valid Python - I was trying to visualize it)

Comment: .. And `word[0]` will always return the first word (`Contact`)?

Comment: I just wanted you to understand the idea. Code in the answer is edited to match your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
bottoms = []
for w in word_list:
    bottoms.append(w["bottom"])

current_row = []
row_list = []
key = sorted(bottoms)[0]
threshold = float("10")
for b in sorted(bottoms):
    if abs(b-key) <= threshold:
        idx = bottoms.index(b)
        current_row.append(word_list[idx])
    else:
        row_list.append(current_row)
        idx = bottoms.index(b)
        current_row = [word_list[idx]]
        key = b

for row in row_list:
    print(row)
```

This always thresholds compared to the lowest value starting a new row, and output is

```
[{'bottom': Decimal('58.650'), 'text': 'Contact'}]
[{'bottom': Decimal('74.101'), 'text': 'Oliver'}, {'bottom': Decimal('77.280'), 'text': 'email@domain.com'}]
[{'bottom': Decimal('90.662'), 'text': 'CEO'}]
[{'bottom': Decimal('101.833'), 'text': 'www.domain.com'}]
```